# Microsoft QnA bot Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

Ok so I fallowed all the instructions I could find but after I set up my bot I get only

> { "statusCode": 404, "message": "Resource not found" }

```
var demo=JSON.stringify({"question":"Hi"});

var extServerOptionsPost={
    host:'westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com',
    path:'/knowledgebases/*my_id*/generateAnswer',
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'*my_sub*',
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'Content-Length':Buffer.byteLength(demo)
}
};

var reqPost=http.request(extServerOptionsPost,function(res){
    console.log("response statusCode: ",res.statusCode);
    res.on('data',function(data){
        console.log('Posting Result:\n');
        process.stdout.write(data);
        console.log('\n\n POST Operation Completed');
    });
});


reqPost.write(demo);


reqPost.end();
reqPost.on('error',function(e){
    console.error(e);
});
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hei,

You are using the wrong host.
You can use Host: https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v1.0/knowledgebases//generateAnswer
or https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/qnamaker/v2.0/knowledgebases/{knowledgeBaseID}/generateAnswer

Also, you can check complete documentation of v2.0 here:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa

BR

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't even notice!

Comment: you have to update alterations (PATCH) and train KB (also PATCH). here a good guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/guides/active-learning-qnamaker